# Determine file extension

Tags: python, file

I tried to solve the following problem by creating a new file, then tried each one of these functions to get the file extension but all i got was errors.

What am I doing wrong?

"**Examine the following three functions that take as argument a file name and return the extension of that file. For instance, if the file name is 'myfile.tar.gz' the returned value of the function should be 'gz'. If the file name has no extention, i.e. when the file name is just 'myfile', the function should return an empty string.**"

```
def get_extension1(filename):
    return(filename.split(".")[-1])
def get_extension2(filename):
    import os.path
    return(os.path.splitext(filename)[1])
def get_extension3(filename):
    return filename[filename.rfind('.'):][1:]**
```

Which of the these functions are doing exactly what they are supposed to do according to the description above?

- a) get_extension1 and get_extension3
- b) get_extension3 only
- c) get_extension2 and get_extension3
- d) All of them

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic

Comment: what is the error you getting?

Comment: with get_extension1 i get: AttributeError: built in function or method has no attribute"split"

Comment: the other 2 functions makes the same error but instead of "has no split" it says "has no rfind"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_extension1(filename)` will return the file name if `filename` does not contain `.`

`get_extension3(filename)` will raise an error because of `**` at the end:

```
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`get_extension1` shoud be:

```
def get_extension1(filename):
    output = filename.split(".")
    return output[-1] if len(output)>1 else ''
```

Comment: @Moutaz Mahmoude I hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try it and find out:

```
get_extension1("myfile.ext")
Out[60]: 'ext'

get_extension1("myfile")
Out[61]: 'myfile'                   # wrong

get_extension2("myfile.ext")
Out[62]: '.ext'

get_extension2("myfile")
Out[63]: ''

get_extension3("myfile.ext")
Out[64]: 'ext'

get_extension3("myfile")
Out[65]: ''
```

**Edit:** it sounds like the AttributeErrors are because you are passing something other than a string for `filename`. If filename is a string they run just fine, but `get_extension1` fails if the filename has no extension.